# Select elements from sql table between values and not in a user list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sqlite

I am having some difficulty with selecting some values from an sql table with python. I have a table with 4 columns and many rows, I want to select data from a certain column between some values and more than that I also want to eliminate elements that are between these values that are provided in a form of a list.

I am using python 3 with sqlite, so I have tried to write:

```
c.execute('''SELECT eid,pid,sr,subcase
             FROM ElmStrengthRatio
             WHERE eid BETWEEN ? AND ? AND subcase = ? ''',(firstID,lastID,case))
```

But this only gives me rows for values between values and of a certain subcase. I want to have a list and eliminate from the selection the rows containing the element ids from the list

For example, I have 4 rows with the follwing data

```
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|    Elem ID      |        PID      |    St Ratio     |      SUBCASE    |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        10       |        34       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        11       |        33       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        12       |        33       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        13       |        32       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        14       |        31       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        15       |        38       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        16       |        34       |        12       |        2        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        17       |        35       |        12       |        2        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

I want to select the whole row where:

1. Elem ID is between 11 and 15
2. Subcase is equal to 1
3. And the user input list is [11,12], this means that we need to eliminate from selection the rows containing elem 11 and 12

So, my selection at the end should be the following rows:

```
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        13       |        32       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        14       |        31       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        15       |        38       |        12       |        1        |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

Comment: `11-15` will also include endpoints, so your output is not analogous to what you're expecting from your SQL statement because the `BETWEEN` keyword includes endpoints. Please clarify your output.

Comment: Also if I am interpreting correctly, you want to make a new table and store the result from your query?

Comment: In where-clause add "and eid not in (11, 12)“. As far as I know parametrization is not supported for a list in SQLite.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher for the solution. I have created a temp table with the input list and use your clause as such: 'AND eid NOT IN (SELECT eid FROM tempTable)' and it works.